# How to print a 3D array in Python?

Tags: python

I created a simple 3D array in Python I need to print it in rows.

```
apple=[[["SNo."],["Computers"],["Mobile"]],
       [["1"],["iMac"],["iPhone"]],
        [["2"],["Macbook"],["iPod"]]]
```

I want it to be printed like below:

```
SNo. Computers Mobile
1 iMac iPhone
2 Macbook iPod
```

Comment: How do you need it to look?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do that with:

```
for l in apple:
    print(*[e[0] for e in l])
```

But frankly, since the final elements are all one-element list, I think you should change the code that creates it to have a 2D array to start with. Everything will be easier that way.

Answer (score 1):

That data looks 2D to me. If you really want to print a 3D array, then you can avoid writing any loops yourself and use `numpy`:

```
import numpy as np

apple_np = np.array(apple)
print apple_np
```

Your data, however isn't 3D, so it won't print out as you envisage. What you need is a 2D array:

```
apple=[["SNo.", "Computers", "Mobile"],
       ["1", "iMac", "iPhone"],
       ["2", "Macbook", "iPod"]]

apple_np = np.array(apple)
print apple_np
```

If you're using python 2.7, you can use the following to print out the table in a nice format:

```
width = max([len(el) for row in apple for el in row]) + 1

for row in apple:
    for el in row:
        print ("{:"+str(width)+"s}").format(el),
    print ""
```

Answer (score 0):

it should works:

```
for i in apple:
    for j in i:
        helper.append(j)
    counter = 0
    assistant = []
for x in helper:
    counter += 1
    assistant.append(x[0])
    if counter == 3:
        print(" ".join(assistant))
        counter = 0
        assistant = []
```